# Is it possible to know what time an ODK form was finalized upon submission?

Tags: xforms, odk

I'm creating a form that collects time specific information. Is it possible to find out what time the information was collected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hidden or pre-loaded fields to your form with jr:preload and jr:preloadParams
first define your instance

```
<instance>
   <market id="mkt">
     <colectionTime/>
   </market>
 </instance>
```

then bind it like this

```
<bind nodeset="/market/collectionTime" type="time" jr:preload="timestamp" jr:preloadParams="end"/>
```

More Information Property values (http://opendatakit.org/help/form-design/examples/#preload_params)